# Table View Cell Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have multiple cells in my table view; e.g. Cat Cell, Dog Cell, Chicken Cell. In the Cat Cell I have two views: a graphs view and an images view.

If the graphs view is hidden and the images view is visible, then I want to set my cell height to 200, and 350 in the opposite case.

How would I achieve that? I am registering my nib file in the  `heightForRowAt` delegate method of the table view and I have tried different things to no avail. These are the two views in my cell:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *imagesView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *graphView;
```

...and this is my `heightForRowAt` method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TrainingImageCell *cell = (TrainingImageCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TrainingImageCell"];
    if (cell.isGraphViewOnTop == YES) {
        return 350;
    }
    else {
        return 200;
    }
    return 200;
}
```

Comment: why are registering nib file in heightForRowAt. You are registering new cell hence cannot acces the exiting cell. If you want it working in your style instead of registering new cell in height for row at IndexPath you can access existing cell using indexPath as TrainingImageCell *currentCell = (TrainingImageCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; and check property.

Comment: It is not a valid thing to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method in heightForRowAtIndexPath. Because first heightForRowAtIndexPath method get called and then cellForRowAtIndexPath method will called. If you show me some code of cellForRowAtIndexPath method, may i can help you.

Comment: I got that part @YagneshDobariya i have to use it like mentioned in the answers, but i am having issues now with reload tableview. I have defined a bool property isShowingGraphView and hiding and unhiding my views in cellForRowAt after registering the nib. im calling this property in heightforRowAt and against the bool returning height but if i call reload TableView whole view disappears.

Comment: @UsamabinAttique why are you use TrainingImageCell *cell = (TrainingImageCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TrainingImageCell"]; in heightForRowAtIndexPath. Directly use same condition as you have used to set "isGraphViewOnTop" in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I think problem should be here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of initiating a new cell, you need to access the one what is already in the `tableView`.

Instead of

```
TrainingImageCell *cell = (TrainingImageCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TrainingImageCell"];
```

Do

```
TrainingImageCell *currentCell = (TrainingImageCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And than take a look on the property.

**EDIT:**
Looking at the lengthy discussion we have, here is a very reliable example for an approach you could use in *Swift*.

```
import UIKit

class RightAlignedCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subLabel: UILabel!
    // Your boolean property you would like to map
    var randomBool: Bool = false
}

class RightAlignedTableViewController: UIViewController {
    // This is just an example for the dataSource, you should have this somewhere already
    lazy var dataSource: [Bool] = {
        var dataSource: [Bool] = []
        for index in 0..<10 {
            dataSource.append(index % 2 == 0)
        }
        return dataSource
    }() 

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension RightAlignedTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate {}

extension RightAlignedTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        // Take a look in the !!!dataSource!!!, what is value for isHidden
        let isHidden = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
        // return the right height
        return isHidden ? 60 : 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: RightAlignedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RightAlignedCell", for: indexPath) as! RightAlignedCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Something"
        cell.subLabel.text = "Nothing"
        cell.randomBool = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i am able to access the properties like that what i am trying to do is 
        if (currentCell.graphView setHidden:YES) {
        return 350;
    }
    else {
        return 200;
        } but it is giving me an error, ps isGraphViewOnTop is just a bool so on its own it wouldn't know what to do if set to yes or no. i am using it inside a function somewhere. Pardon my ignorance but is it the right way to approach what i am trying to achieve ?

Comment: No it is not the right approach. Here all you should do is take a look on the flag if it is `true` or `false` and return a value. 
do somewhere -> `[currentCell.graphView setHidden:YES]` and than reload the tableview( [tableView realodData]), so the height will be asked again.

Comment: i am calling ( [tableView realodData]) in my cellForRowAt but the problem is that my whole view disappears whenever i uncomment it. i also tried reloadRowsatindexpath with 0,0 since this cell only gets executed for indexPath =0 but the app crashes if i do that.

Comment: do not call `[tableView reload]` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, that would cause an infinite loop. Where do you set `[currentCell.graphView setHidden:YES]` ?

Comment: I've defined a bool property isShowingGraph in class and i am setting up setHidden against the bool value in cellForRowAt. where i am registering the cell with reuse identifer. if i use your prescribed approach where should i reload data? because if i do it in heightforRowAt the whole view disappears.

Comment: `heightForRowAt` will be called after `cellForRowAt`. So ideally, you do not reload the tableView at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150301/discussion-between-dirtydanee-and-usama-bin-attique).

Answer (score 1):

Why are registering nib file in heightForRowAt. You are registering new cell hence cannot access the existing cell. If you want it working in your style instead of registering new cell in height for row at IndexPath you can access existing cell using indexPath as

```
TrainingImageCell *currentCell = (TrainingImageCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and access check property.

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 TrainingImageCell *currentCell = (TrainingImageCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if (cell.isGraphViewOnTop == YES) {
  return 350;
  }
return 200;
}
```

Comment: Yes i am able to access the properties like that what i am trying to do is if (currentCell.graphView setHidden:YES) { return 350; } else { return 200; } but it is giving me an error, ps isGraphViewOnTop is just a bool so on its own it wouldn't know what to do if set to yes or no. i am using it inside a function somewhere. Pardon my ignorance but is it the right way to approach what i am trying to achieve ?

Comment: Where are you using it?? You must have set flag values to isGraphViewOnTop in cellForRowAtIndexPath then you can use it here.

Comment: You can proper AutoLayout and UIAutomatic Dimension for height for Row.

Comment: if you want to manipulate tableVieCells height according to Graph View is visile or not, I would suggest using UIStackView inside your cell. It manges for visible cmponents only. Check this link  http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/uistackview-table-cells.

Comment: I am using it in a function in my cell class where i am flipping graph view and images view when clicked on a bar button using UIView transitionWithView and not setting the flag anywhere in cellForRowAt. ps the project is pretty huge and a lot of functionality is invoked in the cells so maybe going down that road with UIStackView is not the best option at the moment.

Comment: is your isGraphViewOnTop globally defined in your cell class ?

Comment: Yes its declared globally in the cell class but the flag is not set anywhere, anyway i've defined another bool property in main class with tableview isGraphViewShowing and i've set hidden graph view and image on YES and NO, in cellforRowAt delegate method. Now its still not working cz tableview is not reloaded anywhere, the app crashed when i tried to do reloadRowsAtIndexPath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150293/discussion-between-usama-bin-attique-and-luckyshubhra).

Answer (score 0):

If you `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you just get a new cell, it will not have any data to check if `isGraphViewOnTop`

My advice will be to return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and set cell views with constants, so when the element is hidden, a cell will have a smaller size.